# Jenkins: This site cannot be reached

Tags: nginx, jenkins, ubuntu-18.04

I set up a DigitalOcean server running ubuntu 18.04 and am trying to run Jenkins on it.  I followed the instructions to the letter in this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04

which works perfectly until Step 4. When I enter:
http://your_server_ip_or_domain:8080

substituting the DigitalOcean ip for "your_server_ip_or_domain", of course, the browser says "This site cannot be reached".  Every step before that worked perfectly.  The firewall is open to it.

I also made sure the JRE was installed.

**EDIT**: I read in another tutorial that Jenkins does not support Java 10 or 11, so I removed Java 11 and installed Java 8, and followed this tutorial:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I also installed a web server using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Same error whether I put the ipaddress in the browser or ipaddress:80 or ipaddress:8080. I can ping the ip from outside the network ok.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Nginx is listening on port 80 so you need to open the firewall to that port as well.  Use the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

Now I can get the default web page for nginx by using ipaddress:80 and jenkins by entering ipaddress:8080